# Download a ggplotly() object as a .png through a shiny app which runs in a browser

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Is it possible to download a `ggplotly()` object as .png like a `ggplot()` object in a shiny application which you open in a browser. I have found some ways to download a ggplot but none for ggplotly. If there is no way is there some hacky alternative?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("event"),
  downloadButton("download","Download Plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # renderPlotly() also understands ggplot2 objects!
    save<-reactive({
      plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)

    })
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      ggplotly(save())
    })

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("down", ".png", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(file, plot = save())
    }
  ) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have you tried `?export` ?

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: I feel there's some discrepancy here. `ggplotly()` converts a `ggplot` object to a `plotly` object. In your code, `save()` is already a plotly object; why do `ggplotly(save())`?

Comment: As you do here, just replace `ggsave` with `export`. But you have to install the `webshot` package and `phantom.js`.

Comment: firmo23, I give an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314307/download-plotly-using-downloadhandler/53315597#53315597

Comment: cool thanks stephane

Comment: Why does this not work for svg download as well?