# Is there a way to link a plotly modebar button with an actionButton in Rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am working on an Rshiny app and I would like to download the plots I generate with plotly using an Rshiny actionButton instead of the built-in plotly download button. I have tried downloading the plots with downloadHandler, but for some reason the download window takes a long time to appear, something that doesn't happen when using the modebar's download button. Is there any way to link the plotly modebar download button with an Rshiny actionButton?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a way to download by pressing a button: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317200/1100107

Comment: I had not tried it before and it worked! Thank you very much!